# HTML page to XHTML with TagSoup

Tags: java, parsing, xhtml

Sorry if this is too simple, but I simply couldn't find a tutorial nor the documentation of the Java version of TagSoup.

Basically I want to download an HTML webpage from the internet and turn it into XHTML, contained in a string. How can I do this with TagSoup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this:

```
wget -O - example.com/bad.html | java -jar tagsoup.jar
```

Or, from Java:

> To parse HTML:
>
> - Create an instance of `org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser`
> - Provide your own SAX2 ContentHandler
> - Provide an `InputSource` referring to the HTML
> - And `parse()`!

Comment: Precisely this! I want to get this value into a string in Java.

Comment: @konr, if this answer is precisely what you wanted, you might want to accept/up-vote it =)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which should provide you with a means to pull down a web page and parse it accordingly with TagSoup...

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://streak.espn.go.com/en/?date=20120824");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        // Check if server response is valid
        StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
        if (status.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid response from server: " + status.toString());
        }

        // Pull content stream from response
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

        try
        {
            XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser");

            // Use the TagSoup parser to build an XOM document from HTML
            Document doc = new Builder(parser).build(builder.toString());

            // Push your data to string or XML
            doc.toString();
            doc.toXML();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        { ... }
```

Comment: Next time please include `import` statements.